# OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: not enough data on travis-ci

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I'm making use of the [`google/api_client` library in ruby](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client). My code works fine in development and local test, but not so well on Travis-CI. I'm storing my private key as a multi-line string both locally and on Travis. My code fails here:

```
require "google/api_client"

class GoogleCalendarAdapter
  def key
    OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV["GOOGLE_P12_PEM"], "notasecret")  # line 27
  end
end
```

I have defined the GOOGLE_P12_PEM environmental variable via the Travis-CI web console as:

`"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICXQIBAAK...\n...
\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"`

This is the error I recieve:

```
Failure/Error: events = calendar.fetch_events(start_time, end_time)
 OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError:
   Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: not enough data
 # ./lib/google_calendar_adapter.rb:27:in `initialize'
 # ./lib/google_calendar_adapter.rb:27:in `new'
 # ./lib/google_calendar_adapter.rb:27:in `key'
 # ./lib/google_calendar_adapter.rb:36:in `oauth2_client'
 # ./lib/google_calendar_adapter.rb:49:in `google_api_client'
 # ./lib/google_calendar_adapter.rb:15:in `fetch_events'
 # ./spec/lib/google_calendar_adapter_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up encrypting my p12 file, and providing instructions on how to decrypt the file in my .travis.yml, as documented, [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/#Using-OpenSSL)